# c - struct in struct - valid c? - valid c++? - scope?

Tags: c, struct

I would like to define the following structure and typedef:

```
typedef struct Atype
{
  int A;
  struct
  {
    int VERBOS;
  }
  IO;
}
Atype;
```

In main I then can define variables as:

```
Atype In1,In2;
In1.A=3;
In1.IO.VERBOS=4;
In2.IO=In1.IO;
```

etc.

The code compiles and runs (c - gcc-clang) but I have to write for different environments. My questions:

1) Are these nested structs without name valid c?

2) valid c++?

3) what is the scope of IO?

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid struct in C / C++ and it's called an unnamed struct.  Here is a page from GCC that contains references to it

> http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html

The scope of `IO` is no different than any other field in the struct

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. The same scope as `A`.

Comment: Indeed this perfectly answered my question. I coded it with the intend to have valid C/C++ code and have IO in the same scope as A. However when trying to find the construct I made with the use of Google I got confused and was affright I used some buggy feature of my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion, why not just this?

```
struct IO {
    int VERBOS;
};

typedef struct Atype {
  int A;
  struct IO;
} Atype;
```

Comment: Because this would put IO into the same scope as Atype, whereas the "struct in struct" solution (see below) places it only in the scope of the struct (same as A).

Comment: @mwh Yes I know the difference of scope, but I feel it makes it easier to understand what's going on